# A lot of GC_FOR_ALLOC and sometimes the transfer stops when this warning is like infinite

Tags: android, bitmap, garbage-collection

Ivam facing this problem of memory and it drives me crazy.
My app is receiving binary data from raspberry. With this data Im creating an int array, colors than using it to create my bitmap and display the image. The protocol of transfer is UDP.
No problem when I receive one image, but when I ask my raspberry to send 10 images for example, this message GC_FOR_ALLOC appears and sometimes the transfer stops without sending all images.
I googled this problem, I added Runtime.getRuntime().gc(); System.gc(); to my code and same problem.
I declared all my objects out of the loop to avoid creating each time a new variable, to create my bitmap Im using createBitmap(int[] colors, int width, int height, Bitmap.Config config), I read on the internet that it is not good to do this method and use instead createScaledBitmap(Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, boolean filter).
The problem I do not know how to use my array colors with createScaledBitmap method.
Also, I tried bitmap.recycle at the end of my loop, it sends the first image then I have an error, "trying to use a recycled".
Please can someone help me.
I can add my code if you want. 
Thank you
This is the code:

```
class UDPServer  {
        MainActivity act;

        final String capitalizedSentence = "well received!";
        final byte[] sendData = capitalizedSentence.getBytes();

        public UDPServer(MainActivity act) {
            this.act=act;
        }


        public void connect() throws Exception {
            final  ImageView image = (ImageView) act.findViewById(R.id.imageDisplay);
            final byte[] receiveData1=new byte[40960], receiveData2=new byte[40960], receiveData3=new byte[40960], receiveData4=new byte[40960];
            final DatagramSocket serverSocket=new DatagramSocket(8080);
            final DatagramPacket receivePacket1 = new DatagramPacket(receiveData1, receiveData1.length);
            final DatagramPacket receivePacket2 = new DatagramPacket(receiveData2, receiveData2.length);
            final DatagramPacket receivePacket3 = new DatagramPacket(receiveData3, receiveData3.length);
            final DatagramPacket receivePacket4 = new DatagramPacket(receiveData4, receiveData4.length);

            final Thread udpserver = new Thread()
            {
                    public void run () {



                        try {
                           while (!isInterrupted()) {


                                System.out.println("waiting for the conx");


                                serverSocket.receive(receivePacket1);
                                serverSocket.receive(receivePacket2);
                                serverSocket.receive(receivePacket3);
                                serverSocket.receive(receivePacket4);

                                System.out.println("thank you sir");



                                final Bitmap bitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(act.afficheImage(
                                        receivePacket1.getData(),
                                        receivePacket2.getData(),
                                        receivePacket3.getData(),
                                        receivePacket4.getData()),
                                        320, 256, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);


                                act.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                                    }
                                });
                                InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket1.getAddress();
                                int port = receivePacket1.getPort();
                                System.out.println("From: " + IPAddress + ":" + port);
                                DatagramPacket sendPacket1 = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, port);
                                serverSocket.send(sendPacket1);

                                Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
                                System.gc();
                            }
                            serverSocket.close();
                        } catch (SocketException ex) {
                            System.out.println("UDP Port 8080 is occupied.");
                        } catch (IOException ex1) {
                            System.out.println("Error: " + ex1.getMessage());
                            ex1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
            };
        udpserver.start();
        }
    }
```

this is the method afficheImage:

```
    private static final int WIDTH = 320;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 256;
    public static int a=255<<24;
    public static ByteBuffer buffer1;
    public static short[] array=new short[WIDTH * HEIGHT];
    public static byte[] si=new byte[2];
    public static int[] colors = new int[WIDTH * HEIGHT];
    public static int[] afficheImage(byte[] s1, byte[] s2, byte[] s3, byte[] s4){
        try{
            for (int i=0;i<HEIGHT*WIDTH/4;i++){
                si[0] = s1[2*i];
                si[1] = s1[2*i+1];
                buffer1 = ByteBuffer.wrap(si);
                buffer1.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
                array[i]=buffer1.getShort();
            }

            for (int i=0;i<HEIGHT*WIDTH/4;i++){
                si[0] = s2[2*i];
                si[1] = s2[2*i+1];
                buffer1 = ByteBuffer.wrap(si);
                buffer1.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
                array[i+s1.length/2]=buffer1.getShort();
            }

            for (int i=0;i<HEIGHT*WIDTH/4;i++){
                si[0] = s3[2*i];
                si[1] = s3[2*i+1];
                buffer1 = ByteBuffer.wrap(si);
                buffer1.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
                array[i+s1.length]=buffer1.getShort();
            }

            for (int i=0;i<HEIGHT*WIDTH/4;i++){
                si[0] = s4[2*i];
                si[1] = s4[2*i+1];
                buffer1 = ByteBuffer.wrap(si);
                buffer1.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
                array[i+3*s1.length/2]=buffer1.getShort();
            }


            int delta=foundMax(array)-foundMin(array);
            int min=foundMin(array);

            int r;

            for (int i=0;i<HEIGHT*WIDTH;i++) {
                r = (array[i] - min) * 255/delta;
                colors[i] = a | (r << 16) | (r << 8) | r;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return colors;
    }
```

Comment: What are the dimensions of the images the Raspberry is sending? Also, do you know the pixel config e.g. ARGB_8888?

Comment: I answered a question from you earlier about decoding an image.  Is the Raspberry sending you an encoded image like PNG or JPEG instead of raw pixel data?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you're using.

Comment: @krislarson, yes it's ARGB_8888, WIDTH = 320, HEIGHT = 256

Comment: I just updated my question, I added the code of my udpServer, I can add the method afficheImage, it just creates my array colors

Comment: Yes, please add the afficheImage code.

Comment: I just did it. Thank you for your help

Comment: When you ask for say, 10 images, what are you doing with those - are you trying to display them all at once?

Comment: I have a camera sending images to my server and I want to display it as a video, so Im not trying to display them all at once, but one after the other so I can create sort of video, do you see what I mean

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Okay, here's the *real* answer:

You need to use OpenGL.

OpenGL would be a lot faster and maybe actually make your app look like a video, which is what you want.

The great thing for your use case is that OpenGL renders in a background thread, so you can build your pixel buffer from network data and render it all in the same thread.

---

The code is actually creating a new `Bitmap` with every "frame", so you should also allocate one static bitmap as well.

At the start of the `connect` method where you allocate the `DatagramPacket`s, you should allocate your `Bitmap` too:

```
    final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(320, 256, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Then inside your loop after you get all your data:

```
            int[] pixels = act.afficheImage(
                    receivePacket1.getData(),
                    receivePacket2.getData(),
                    receivePacket3.getData(),
                    receivePacket4.getData());

            bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, 320, 0, 0, 320, 256);
```

You might also need some synchronization on the bitmap between the server thread that is pushing buffer data into it and the UI thread that is trying to render it into the `ImageView`.

Is there any way you can throttle the data coming from the Raspberry?  It's possible that your Android device might be getting overwhelmed trying to handle the network data and display the image at the same time.

I can also see a bunch of other optimizations for eliminating most of those temporary work buffers, but those wouldn't really move the needle when it comes to getting rid of the OOM exceptions.

Comment: thank you for your response, can you tell me more about the other optimizations.

Comment: 1) Make a single datagram byte buffer, say, `byte[4096]` and reuse that buffer by receiving the byte data, processing that, then receiving more data, etc.  2) Do the pixel processing directly into the `int[] colors` pixel array and get rid of the `short[] array` buffer.  I see you are doing on-the-fly contrast enhancement, so 3) eliminate the second pass over the data by having brightness and contrast parameters that you apply to the data immediately.

Comment: 4) Instead of creating the `int[] colors` array for each picture, create a single `int[320*256]` array and reuse that.  5) Since you don't need any alpha in your output, you could consider using an RGB_565 format for your bitmap which will cut the size of your bitmap in half.  Like I said, these are all just minor improvements.

Comment: I changed my code, Im even using cache memory to save my bitmap. Im still having GC_for_alloc

Comment: it's so nice of you to help me. I will optimize my code like you said and tell you.